# How to create dictionary from bytes (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to create a list from an API call, the data comes out like this which I believe is bytes.

Nothing sensitive below here:

> [{"Udid":"00000004324234235","SerialNumber":"SN42A32A34","MacAddress":"00127F287220","Imei":"","EasId":"443243434225346FE9","AssetNumber":"","DeviceFriendlyName":"00:16:7F:18:7C:B0 ","LocationGroupId":{"Id":{"Value":544},"Uuid":"364243f-97342b-4287-9333-b942442313","Name":"Location2"},"LocationGroupName":"Location2","UserId":{"Id":{"Value":5111},"Uuid":"364243f-97342b-4287-9333-b942442313","Name":"MDM Enroll"},"UserName":"Enroll123","UserEmailAddress":"enroll123@nitro.com","Ownership":"C","PlatformId":{"Id":{"Value":10},"Name":"PalmPhone"},"Platform":"PalmPhone","ModelId":{"Id":{"Value":44},"Name":"PalmPhone - X101Nitro"},"Model":"PalmPhone - X101Nitro","OperatingSystem":"1.7.44444","PhoneNumber":"","LastSeen":"2018-11-11T07:46:57.257","EnrollmentStatus":"Enrolled","ComplianceStatus":"Compliant","CompromisedStatus":false,"LastEnrolledOn":"2018-11-09T18:26:03.610","LastComplianceCheckOn":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000","LastCompromisedCheckOn":"2018-06-13T19:28:22.933","IsSupervised":false,"DeviceMCC":{"SIMMCC":"","CurrentMCC":""},"VirtualMemory":0,"IsDeviceDNDEnabled":false,"IsDeviceLocatorEnabled":false,"IsCloudBackupEnabled":false,"IsActivationLockEnabled":false,"IsNetworkTethered":false,"IsRoaming":false,"SystemIntegrityProtectionEnabled":false,"ProcessorArchitecture":0,"Id":{"Value":140},"Uuid":"364243f97342b42879333-b942442313"},

Then it repeats with the same format just different data. I tried doing something along the lines of `(ast.literal_eval(b"myList"))` (myList being the variable that holds all of the above).

Any ideas?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp  the text you just described was JSON. API calls usually give you back JSON. You first need to de serialize that then i believe it turns into a list that you can manipulate from there.

Answer (score 2):

If the returned string is valid json, you can process it like so:

```
import json
x = json.loads(myList)
```

`x` will then contain the list of dictionaries that the API call returned.

`ast.literal_eval(myList)` should also work - if myList is actually of type `bytes` like you indicated, try `ast.literal_eval(myList.decode('UTF-8'))`

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your API return, is that it's a list and the dictionary from the first element, contains some fields as "false", but they are not encapsulated with "" as strings, and python only recognizes "False", with capital F.

So you should first convert the response to text, then replace the `false` for `False`, and as last point use json.loads to use the Json on your code: (where `api_return` is what your receive)

```
response = str(api_return[0])
response.replace("false", "False")
response_json = json.loads(response)
```

Comment: good catch. if thats the cause the OP should probably be careful with the replace though.  Basically a regex that makes sure it’s not part of a string. but... i would have expected the python side json module to know about false/False

Comment: Indeed a regex solution would be safer. The Json module doesn't handle well variations such as case sensitivity @JLPeyret!
@RyanAdams could tell if it fits, and in positive case I can update the code to add the regex solution